# Is there a way to restrict a linux user in a Dockerfile to only be allowed to run some specific commands?

Tags: linux, security, dockerfile

I'm creating a Dockerfile with Fedora as base image. I created an user and I want this user to only be allowed to run basic commands (touch, echo, git).

I already tried modifying the sudoers file and pointing the PATH variable to another folder but none of these solutions have worked also I tried changing the permissions of the commands `chmod 700 /bin/ln` but this affects all the commands in `/bin` instead of that specific one, so the user cannot run any command after that. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Make their login shell a restricted shell.